# Creating array with certain type and adding items under it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a array with weapon type. Example: `Bayonet` and each item which has a name type `Bayonet` in it should be added under there.

Here is code for creating the type:

```
var weaponType = item.split(' | ');
weaponType = weaponType[0];
budgetSkins[weaponType] = [];
```

But I'm not sure how can I add it there under the right weaponType. I tried using a `if budgetSkins[weaponType]` but that doesn't work of course because I have to check for the root name but I'm not sure how could I do that.

Here is example weapon types:
`Bayonet`
`M9 Bayonet`
`Karambit`

Example items: `Bayonet | White` `Karambit | Yellow` `M9 Bayonet | Golden`

What I'm trying to achieve

```
{
    "M9 Bayonet": [
        "M9 Bayonet | White"
    ],
    "Bayonet": [
        "Bayonet | Golden"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide any example of the result you try to achieve?

Comment: I have edited my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a little bit more variables and append a required array like this:

```
var item = "Bayonet | White";
var budgetSkins = {};
var parsedItem = item.split(' | ');
var weaponType = parsedItem[0];
if (!budgetSkins[weaponType]) {
    budgetSkins[weaponType] = [];
}

budgetSkins[weaponType].push(item);
```